# how to shift column labels to left python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe i want to move column name to left from specific column. original dataframe have many columns can not do this by rename columns

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,4,7,8,11,1,15,20,15,16,87],
                 'H':[1,3,4,7,8,11,1,15,78,15,16,87],
                 'N':[1,3,4,98,8,11,1,15,20,15,16,87],
                 'p':[1,3,4,9,8,11,1,15,20,15,16,87],
                 
                 'B':[1,3,4,6,8,11,1,19,20,15,16,87],
                 'y':[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]})

print((df))
     A   H   N   p   B  y
0    1   1   1   1   1  0
1    3   3   3   3   3  0
2    4   4   4   4   4  0
3    7   7  98   9   6  0
4    8   8   8   8   8  1
5   11  11  11  11  11  1
6    1   1   1   1   1  1
7   15  15  15  15  19  0
8   20  78  20  20  20  0
9   15  15  15  15  15  0
10  16  16  16  16  16  0
11  87  87  87  87  87  0
```

Here i want to remove label N first dataframe after removing label N

```
    A   H       p   B  y
0    1   1   1   1   1  0
1    3   3   3   3   3  0
2    4   4   4   4   4  0
3    7   7  98   9   6  0
4    8   8   8   8   8  1
5   11  11  11  11  11  1
6    1   1   1   1   1  1
7   15  15  15  15  19  0
8   20  78  20  20  20  0
9   15  15  15  15  15  0
10  16  16  16  16  16  0
11  87  87  87  87  87  0
```

Rrquired output:

```
     A   H   P   B   y  
0    1   1   1   1   1  0
1    3   3   3   3   3  0
2    4   4   4   4   4  0
3    7   7  98   9   6  0
4    8   8   8   8   8  1
5   11  11  11  11  11  1
6    1   1   1   1   1  1
7   15  15  15  15  19  0
8   20  78  20  20  20  0
9   15  15  15  15  15  0
10  16  16  16  16  16  0
11  87  87  87  87  87  0
```

Here last column can be ignore

Note: in original dataframe have many columns , can not rename columns , so need some auto method to shift column names lef

Comment: How do you identify the column whose name you want to remove: by name or by position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
df.columns=sorted(df.columns.str.replace('N',''),key=lambda x : x=='')
df
     A   H   p   B   y   
0    1   1   1   1   1  0
1    3   3   3   3   3  0
2    4   4   4   4   4  0
3    7   7  98   9   6  0
4    8   8   8   8   8  1
5   11  11  11  11  11  1
6    1   1   1   1   1  1
7   15  15  15  15  19  0
8   20  78  20  20  20  0
9   15  15  15  15  15  0
10  16  16  16  16  16  0
11  87  87  87  87  87  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the columns with your own custom list.

```
>>> cols = list(df.columns)
>>> cols.remove('N')
>>> df.columns = cols + ['']
```

Output

```
>>> df
     A   H   p   B   y   
0    1   1   1   1   1  0
1    3   3   3   3   3  0
2    4   4   4   4   4  0
3    7   7  98   9   6  0
4    8   8   8   8   8  1
5   11  11  11  11  11  1
6    1   1   1   1   1  1
7   15  15  15  15  19  0
8   20  78  20  20  20  0
9   15  15  15  15  15  0
10  16  16  16  16  16  0
11  87  87  87  87  87  0
```